# Subtracting samples in R

Tags: r

In this code, I have selected a random sample of 30 and from this random sample of 30 taken a sample of 15.

I am stuck on how to subtract the sample of 15 that I took  from the sample of 30. I.E subtract s1985 from b1985

Can someone help me please?

My code is below

```
function(df, n) df[sample(nrow(df), n), , drop = FALSE]

sample.df(subset(df, YEAR == "1985"), 30)

b1985 <-sample.df(subset(df, YEAR == "1985"), 30)

s1985 <-sample.df(subset(b1985), 15)

sample.df(subset(df, YEAR == "1986"), 30)

b1986 <-sample.df(subset(df, YEAR == "1986"), 30)

s1986 <-sample.df(subset(b1986), 15)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data? `dput(head(df)) ` and paste it here.

Comment: Hey I figured it out but if you can tell me how to multiply the two sums below in my answer and export that as a new variable I would be grateful. The data set is big so here is a link to it instead:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B91hc718u5JxcGR0WjJaYlhPSXM

Answer (score -1):

Hi all I have figured out how to do the subtraction.

1. Rename the rows so they are not the random rows drawn

row.names(b1985) <- 1:nrow(b1985)

row.names(s1985) <- 1:nrow(b1985)

row.names(b1986) <- 1:nrow(b1986)

row.names(s1986) <- 1:nrow(s1986)

2. Subtract by column number (in this case I want to add column 5)

b1985[1:30,5]-s1985[1:15,5]

b1986[1:30,5]-s1986[1:15,5]